# Excel formula that automatically changes the date for a filename when using a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, vlookup

Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Approved Contractors 08302018.xlsx]Contractor with key'!$B$2:$C$99999,2,0)
```

The file name for the spreadsheet named "Approved Contractors 08302018.xlsx" will change next week to "Approved Contractors 09062018.xlsx". The tab name in the spreadsheet is called "Contractor with key".

Currently, I have to go into the formula, update the date after the file name, then paste it into excel, then copy it down to all the cells. How to get I get it to update automatically. I was thinking `=today()-8` but I'm not sure how to do it inside a vlookup for a file name?

Comment: How many of these are there? Do you want to use a volatile worksheet function on all of them? Is the external workbook always open? Does the sequence ever change due to holiday or other?

Comment: The dates will always be today's date? It is not clear how this date change occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

**1.** You only change the date in the filename (ex. only the 08302018 part)

**2.** This date is always formatted as mmddyyyy

**3.** This date is always `=TODAY()-8`

**4.** All other details remain the same (e.g worksheet name, source file being in the same folder as destination file, return values under column C, etc...)

Then you can use the `INDIRECT` function to automatically change that date within the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'[Approved Contractors "&TEXT(TODAY()-8,"mmddyyyy")&".xlsx]Contractor with key'!$B$2:$C$99999"),2,0)
```

However, I noticed that your example goes against the 3rd assumption, and that instead of referencing it to `TODAY()-8`, you want to reference it to the `THURSDAY` date of that current week. In that case, you just need to change the reference date in the above formula. Kindly consider the formula below:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'[Approved Contractors "&TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+5,"mmddyyyy")&".xlsx]Contractor with key'!$B$2:$C$99999"),2,0)
```

To clarify, what this does is it changes the date in reference filename within the formula to the `THURSDAY` date of the current week. So when you run it in your file today (9/15/2018), the reference filename should be *"Approved Contractors 09132018.xlsx"*.

If this returns an error, it may mean the supposed reference file was incorrectly named. In this case using an `IFERROR` function would alert us to check the reference filename. When an error does happen, the following formula would display *"Please check reference filename"*:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'[Approved Contractors "&TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+5,"mmddyyyy")&".xlsx]Contractor with key'!$B$2:$C$99999"),2,0),"Please check reference filename")
```

Comment: I will double check this on Friday and leave a more detailed response. I did a quick test and it seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: So the one that worked the best was the first vlookup formula you provided. =VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT("'[Approved Contractors "&TEXT(TODAY()-8,"mmddyyyy")&".xlsx]Contractor with key'!$B$2:$C$99999"),2,0)
If there is a Friday where we can't run this for some reason I can mess with it at that time but this is perfect for now. Thank you!