# VBA formula that automatically changes the date for a filename when using a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

A new workbook is created each day (sometimes multiple times a day) with a name for example, "Inventory 09-01-2019 0330.xlsm. The date and time (0330 for 3:30) changes every time the file is created. I have found VBA to open the most recently created file (http://www.xl-central.com/open-the-latest-file-in-a-folder.html) but I am having a hard time finding any code that will do that same type of search for the most recent name in a VBA vlookup. 
There is a good suggestion her for how to use indirect in a normal vlookup ([Excel formula that automatically changes the date for a filename when using a vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339282/excel-formula-that-automatically-changes-the-date-for-a-filename-when-using-a-vl)) however I just do not have the knowledge or ability to get this into VBA. Still learning VBA at the moment and this is just too complicated to me.

I want to be able to run the macro, have it open the most recent file in a folder, then activate the vlookup that finds that opened/named file, to pull in data from the same sheet/column into the new workbook being created. Example: New workbook sheet "Agents" contains a blank column for "Comments". I want to vlookup the "Comments" from the "Agents" sheet, in the most recently created workbook in the folder.
I would include examples of what I have tried so far but I fear they are so far off, its just not worth it. 
Thank you.

Comment: The macro that opens the file can easily get the filename, then insert VLOOKUPs using said filename as required.

Comment: Which was a thought that I had, but I had no success inputting it into the vlookup formula.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include the code you have so we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) a code done by Coder375 that returns an array of available names in a given folder. It goes like this:

```
Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    listfiles = vaArray

End Function
```

With that, it's fairly simple to achieve what you need. Just iterate through each entry in the array, and evaluate the name, according to the structure you've brought up. I came up with the below:

- Function to determine the last date from array:

  ```
  Function LastEntry(ByVal myArray As Variant)
  Dim element As Variant
  Dim reference, timeReference As String
  Dim myDate, mostRecentDate, myTime, mostRecentTime As Date

  For Each element In myArray
      reference = CStr(element)

      myDate = CDate(Mid(reference, 11, 10))

      If mostRecentDate Is Null Then mostRecentDate = myDate
      Else
          If DateDiff("d", mostRecentDate, myDate) < 0 Then
              mostRecentDate = myDate

              timeReference = ConvertTime(Mid(reference, 22, 4))
              myTime = CDate(timeReference)
              If mostRecentTime Is Null Then mostRecentTime = myTime
              Else
                  If DateDiff("h", mostRecentTime, myTime) < 0 Then
                      mostRecentTime = myTime
                  End If
              End If
          End If
      End If
  Next element
  LastEntry = CStr(mostRecentDate) & " " & CStr(mostRecentTime)
  End Function
  ```
- Function to return the corrected string from time value found on name:

  ```
  Function ConvertTime(ByVal myString As String)

  Dim hour, amPm, concatenated As String

  hour = Left(myString, 2)

  Select Case hour
      Case "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "24"
          amPm = "AM"
          concatenated = hour
      Case "12"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = hour
      Case "13"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "01"
      Case "14"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "02"
      Case "15"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "03"
      Case "16"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "04"
      Case "17"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "05"
      Case "18"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "06"
      Case "19"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "07"
      Case "20"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "08"
      Case "21"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "09"
      Case "22"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "10"
      Case "23"
          amPm = "PM"
          concatenated = "11"
  End Select
  concatenated = concatenated & ":" & Right(myString, 2) & " " & amPm
  ConvertTime = concatenated
  End Function
  ```

I think this can help you address the issue you have. I couldn't find time to test my second snippet, but I reckon it will work as an acceptable reference for you to build your solution.